# Computing Remy Sigrist sequence A279125

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, oeis

I am curious to understand how you can compute sequences like this one by Rémy Sigrist https://oeis.org/A279125

You can also see it in action in this numberphile video: 
https://youtu.be/j0o-pMIR8uk?t=371

---

What I struggle with is to understand how to compute these 'overlaps' they explain. I don't even know the right term for it... I guess it is connected to lowest order bit, but I don't understand it.

I started writing a function for it, but I need help with computing this bit comparison.

```
function remyF(n) {
    let num = parseInt(n, 10);
    return num.toString(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python:

```
def remyF(n):
  if is_power_of_2(n):
    return 0
  friends = []
  for m in range(1,n):
    if m&n!=0: #true iff m and n share a bit
      friends.append(remyF(m))
  for k in range(max(friends)+1):
      if k not in friends:
        return k 
  return max(friends)+1 #return the first integer in 0...n that is not in friends
```

You should have no issue with `is_power_of_2`. Thanks to Peter Foreman for informing me of numerous errors. And you should store previously computed values in a lookup table if you're going to use this code for any medium to large n.

Comment: @PeterForeman I just tested in Idle, it seems 1 == True but not 5 == True

Comment: @PeterForeman fixed and verified until n=29 where my naive code begins to stall. Thanks very much for all the comments!

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys, this worked. I refactored it for javaScript because I am using it there and it wasn't too hard. I see I need to do some reading on bitwise operators. Can I actually ask you to break down the code and explain actually what's happening? And how can I implement 'previously computed values in a lookup table'?

Comment: @michelangelo re: lookup table- every time you compute a value of remyF, put it in some remyF_list, and then look here for the value of remyF instead of computing it again in the future. re: breaking down the code, I think the code and comments should be clear, but if not, which part?

Comment: Well, with a chance of appearing very stupid, I must say I don't get the logic of this sequence. I completely missed Peter Foreman's answer, as he explained in more detail, but I must say it's deep water for me. E.g. 1. Why do we return 0 when a number is a power of 2? 2. What does 'sharing a bit' really means (should it not be repeated if we compare them in lowest order bit or smth else)? 3. What does k even do? I don't seen it being added to the list? *** If this is too much of an explanation, I would be grateful if you point in the right direction so I can understand this well. Thank you!

Comment: [2] "sharing a bit" would be having a 1 in the same place in their binary expansion. so $2=10_2$ (subscript 2 just means its a binary number) shares a bit with $3=11_2$ (the e.g. from the video). This makes `2&3=2`(since $2=10_2$). [1] a power of 2 in binary is written like $1000\dots0_2$. $2^n$ is the first number with a 1 in the $n$th position. All the zeros means it doesnt "share a bit" with any smaller number. [3] k deals with the 'lexicographically smallest' part of the definition. It needs to be the smallest number not already in `friends`. @michelangelo

Comment: PS @michelangelo the code would have worked just fine if you only gave it the initial condition `remyF(1)=0` but the power of two thing took no effort to implement, and so I did. And also if it wasn't clear, for the lookup table, the main speedup would come from replacing the "pure-recursive" line `friends.append(remyF(m))` with `friends.append(remyF_list(m))`. Once this list is created, it costs basically nothing, compared to recomputing `remyF(m)` again

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns the first $n+1$ terms (terms $0-n$) of the given sequence. It is equivalent to the code used on the OEIS but in Python.

```
def remy(n):
    terms=[0]*n
    for i in range(n+1):
        a=0
        while terms[a]&i:
            a+=1
        terms[a]+=i
        yield a
```

First we create a list full of zeroes. This list is used to store the bits which associate a number to a group (e.g. all numbers whose sequence value is $1$). Each number is iterated through from $0-n$ in order and the program finds which value/group the number is associated to by using a bitwise AND (`&` in Python). When it has done so (the bitwise AND returns zero/False), this number is added to the same position in the list in order to store the bit pattern of this number. Then, to check if future numbers are within this group, the operation of bitwise AND will cause any number containing these bits to be identified (bitwise AND does not return zero/False in this case). The value of the number in the sequence is then yielded.